# Exiting block insert mode with Ctrl-C

Tags: vim

In vim, if you are in block insert mode (`Ctrl-V, Shift-I`) and exit using `Ctrl-C` (instead of `Esc`), it cancels the block edit (and only edits the first row).

Why is this? In almost all other contexts, `Ctrl-C` and `Esc` are synonymous.  (And ideally there's a way to fix this -- I've now gotten used to doing `Ctrl-C` and it would be a shame if I had to relearn…)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> are not guaranteed to be synonymous, and often differ.  For example, in *Insert* mode, <kbd>Esc</kbd> will trigger abbreviations and go to *Normal* mode, whereas <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> will not trigger abbreviations nor the `InsertLeave` autocommand and go straight to *Normal* mode.  Another example is in the old `vi` command line mode, <kbd>Esc</kbd> would actually execute the command as if you had hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  Vim deliberately changed this because that behavior was deemed unintuitive and surprising, but you can still enable it by adding `x` to `'cpoptions'`.

As for the blockwise visual operators, the `blockwise-operators` help tag has the following documentation:

```
Visual-block Insert                     *v_b_I*
With a blockwise selection, I{string}<ESC> will insert {string} at the start
of block on every line of the block, provided that the line extends into the
block.  Thus lines that are short will remain unmodified.  TABs are split to
retain visual columns.
```

Notice that only `Esc` is mentioned, not `Ctrl-c`.

So, no, <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> are not equivalent.  It is never a shame to disabuse oneself of a misconception.  Once you have realized that, you can decide what to do next.  Immediately obvious options are to learn the differences and use the correct key, or decide that you don't need the functionality of one of the keys and remap it to match the other.

Comment: Gotcha. For now I'll `vnoremap <C-c> <Esc>` but I'll keep what you said in mind.

Comment: @BenAlpert: you actually need nnoremap an inoremap with the same values to completely switch to ctrl-c as Esc. I've been using it like this for years now and it's works perfectly for me. It's a shame that other vi variants, like vile or nvi do not allow this workaround, so I'm missing out on abbr functionality there.

Answer (score 0):

Try `:map ^C esc` where "^C" is entered via  <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? What other side effects might it have?

Comment: They serve slightly different functions. CTRL+C conventionally means "cancel this action" (in a unix-like context). Cancelling the action in your vim context means "stop what is happening and go back to normal mode". Escape in vim means, "I've finished go back to normal mode".

Comment: As to side-effects, I didn't notice any. CTRL-C after `:!cat` still seems to have the desired effect after the map. If you encounter problems you could try, e.g. `stty intr \^k` at the shell prompt to change the terminal's interrupt character to CTRL-k.