# Does using ctrl+c instead of esc to exit insert mode break anything in vi?

Tags: vim, vi

When using vi, you can exit insert mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> instead of the more traditional <kbd>Esc</kbd>. Are there any situations where it would be undesirable to use for former instead of the latter? Does it break anything other than best practice?

Comment: It is undesirable to hit the former by accident, which gets you an error-like `Type  :quit<Enter>  to exit Vim` and made me Google how to get back. Hitting `i` gets you right back to insert mode.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> and <kbd>Esc</kbd> are not the same in `vi`/`vim` in most modes, including insert mode.  The difference is <kbd>Esc</kbd> triggers abbreviations while <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> does not.  Whether this matters to you depends on whether you or any plugins you use make use of abbreviations.

---

<sup>Note that it is safer to assume <kbd>Esc</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> do *not* mean the same thing in `vim`.  Another [example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42419/9537) from this same site is when exiting block insert mode (not in `vi`).</sup>

Comment: Good to know, but my question was about exiting insert mode.

Comment: @MDMarra Doh, misread your question.  Insert mode is still different: see updated answer.

Comment: Here's the most important difference I've had to deal with: multiline insert with visual block mode works with Esc and not with C-c.

Answer (score 8):

If you're referring to `vim`, there is a slight difference. `CTRL-C` does not check for abbreviations, and it does not trigger the `InsertLeave` event. So if your plugins have defined any `autocmd` statements that depend on `InsertLeave`, they won't get triggered.

From the official documentation http://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html :

```
<Esc> or CTRL-[ End insert or Replace mode, go back to Normal mode.  Finish
                abbreviation.

CTRL-C          Quit insert mode, go back to Normal mode.  Do not check for
                abbreviations.  Does not trigger the InsertLeave autocommand
                event.
```

You can define a mapping for `CTRL-C` to `<esc>`, then it will trigger `InsertLeave`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean `vim`, not `vi`.

This does indeed work in `vim`, though I wouldn't use it unless I was 100% sure I would never touch a non-Linux operating system, ever. The reason is that other OSes may have their own implementations of `vi`, which do not implement this, and you might find that when running `vi` on those platforms, Ctrl-C has its own traditional behavior: interrupt the process and leave your terminal in a weird state.

Comment: Can you point to any `vi` implementation that still exists today that doesn't handle `Ctrl-C`?  See [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53637/9537) for the real difference.

Comment: @jw013 I guess this answer switches the terminal with vim in a terminal. I do not think that there is another vi/vim anywhere that can interrupt the terminal's process since even in a vim that is embedded in the terminal, you are *either in vim mode, or you are not*. You cannot just have terminal and vim at the same time. In Alacritty which embeds vim, you press `Ctrl+Space` to enter the vim mode. I do not see why there should be any vi/vim on any OS out there that will interrupt a terminal process when you press `Ctrl+C`.