# Vim: Exit single character replace mode with <C-C> when using `nnoremap <C-C> <silent> <C-C>`

Tags: vim

I've become far too trained to use `<C-C>` to return to normal mode. I understand there is [a difference between `<C-C>` and `<ESC>`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42419/40269) but that's beside the point of this question.

I use the mapping `nnoremap <C-C> <silent> <C-C>` so I don't see the message "Type :quit<Enter> to exit vim" when pressing `<C-C>` in normal mode.

When in normal mode and pressing `r` I can't cancel with `<C-C>`, instead it will just insert the non printable character. Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: Your <C-C> is Ctrl+C, right?

Comment: I've updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, that

```
nnoremap <C-C> <silent> <C-C>
```

has the `<silent>` parameter in the wrong position; it works, but not the way you think it does (and it beeps). Better use this:

```
nnoremap <C-C> <Nop>
```

To avoid the insertion of `^C` when aborting `r`, define a special mapping for that, too:

```
nnoremap r<C-c> <Nop>
```